# PyDev "_module_not_in_pythonpath_" breaking code completion

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Goal: **Working code-completion and code-analysis within PyDev.**

Problem: Code completion is not working, probably due to this error I see when I hover over any of my import statements: `"_client_ Found at: _module_not_in_pythonpath_"`. Note, my code actually runs without any problems at all. This is an IDE problem not a Python problem.

The specific statement:

**`from client import NetworkClient`**

The source file (`examples.py`) and the other module (`client.py`) are both in the same folder. Their parent folder is named under `Project | Properties | PYTHONPATH | Source Folders`.

When I run

```
import sys; 
print '\n'.join(sys.path)
```

It does indeed display their directory as part of the path.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong, if anything?

This is the third development environment I've tried opening in PyDev, and it seems like every time getting code completion or code analysis up and running is an uphill battle! I understand dynamic and other languages present challenges, but this case seems rather straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

(This should be a Comment)

(PyDev 2.7.1.2012100913, eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800)

I think it's a PyDev [parsing] problem with PythonPath, I'm finding a similar issue when trying to use an EFS (rse://) folder within the project.

The project fine runs on its remote platform.